# com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration cannot load <context-param> value inside web fragment

Tags: java, jsf, geronimo

I have a web and web-fragment project. In side web-fragment project I use jsf. I would like to prevent jsf render the comment by set this value in web-fragment.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But when debuging I see that WebConfiguration can only see the all `<context-param>`s in side web.xml

I would like to know is there any way to make this class load `<context-param>`s inside web-fragment.xml

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Currently I use Geronimo version 3.0.1. 

When deploying application in to tomcat server, it works ok. Tomcat collects all context-param from web.xml and web-fragment.xml

Answer (score 0):

I have already checked the implementation of GERONIMO version 3.0.1. It is a bug of GERONIMO. In the MergeHelper class, it missed the initialization for ContextParamMergeHandler to merge all `<context-param>`s from web-fragment to web project.

[Here is the way that I fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq1mA.png)